# How can I untar a bunch of same packages inside a same folder?

Tags: linux, bash

I got a problem on untar a list of .tar.gz file in a directory.

In my directory,

there are lots of result.tar.gz , they are the same name, they are renamed as...

```
result.tar.gz
result (1).tar.gz
result (2).tar.gz
result (3).tar.gz
result (4).tar.gz
....
....
....
....
```

I want to untar all of them in one linux command. 
so I try to use

```
tar zxvf *
```

or

```
tar zxvf result*.tar.gz
```

both got this error

```
tar: result (3).tar.gz: Not found in archive
tar: result (4).tar.gz: Not found in archive
tar: result (5).tar.gz: Not found in archive
tar: result (6).tar.gz: Not found in archive
```

Who knows how to untar all of the packages at the same time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`tar` only knows how to process one .tar file at a time: the one specified with `f`. If you specify additional names on the command line they are interpreted as files to extract from the specified .tar file.

Most of the answers so far do not account for unusual file names e.g., those containing spaces, newlines or other special characters).

The correct answer is this:

```
for file in *.tar.gz ; do
    tar xzf "$file"
fi
```

The other acceptable answer would be to use `find`

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.tar.gz' -exec tar xzf {} \;`
```

Why can't I...

- Use `ls *.tar.gz | ...` ?

  Because `ls` will clobber certain characters in file names (ie, it is not safe). If you must use `ls` for this you should be careful to use `ls -1` and then be careful that you treat newline and only newline as a record seperator. This is still not safe, but it's safer.
- Use `$file` without the quotes?

  Because a file with spaces in the name, among other things, will be interpreted in ways you do not expect. Example: A file named `monthly backup.tar.gz` will be interpreted as `tar xzf monthly backup.tar.gz` and you will get an error because the archive `monthly` does not exist.
- Use `echo | xargs tar` ?

  Because `echo` will mangle file names, specifically ones with spaces in the name.

When performing a `while read` loop you almost always want to use `read -r`, which will prevent backslashes in the input from being interpreted as escape sequences. If you had a file named `foo\bar` then `read` without `-r` would not read it correctly.

EDIT:

Per comments, here's a method for extracting tarballs into subdirectories.

```
for file in *.tar.gz ; do
    # strip any leading path information from the file name
    name_only="${file##*/}"

    # strip the extension .tar.gz
    without_extension="${name_only%.tar.gz}"

    # make a directory named after the tar file, minus extension
    mkdir -p "$without_extension"

    # extract the file into its own directory
    tar xzf "$file" -C "$without_extension"
done
```

Above I extract into directories named after the tarball. However, any scheme for making unique directory names would be sufficient. For example, here's a version that extracts to sequentially numbered directories:

```
let n=0
for file in *.tar.gz ; do
    mkdir -p "$n";
    tar xzf "$file" -C "$n"

    let n=n+1
done
```

Comment: good answer, but a follow up question is that, now every tar.gz has the same filename inside, when I untar all of them , the new files will override the old files. How can i avoid it by renaming the file name automatically?

Comment: @Kit Ho: This would require a slightly more complicated script which creates a new sub-directory for each script. I will update my answer to include a sample of how to do that.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution, found this through google search. [link](http://lists.pdxlinux.org/pipermail/plug/2005-January/037980.html)

```
for i in *.tar.gz; do tar -xvzf "$i"; done
```

Comment: But that's not obfuscated enough ;) I just like piping because commands can be strung together.

Comment: i prefer piping too, just offering something different in bash. :)
+1 by the way.

Comment: In this case there is no good reason to use pipes - why incur the overhead of spawning an extra process just to do something the shell can already do (generate a list of files) with globbing?  On top of that both pipe answers given so far are subtly broken because they don't handle file names with whitespace correctly.  Using globs in for loops does not have that problem.  Even this answer, which takes the best approach of the three so far, is also broken because `$i` needs to be quoted (`"$i"`).

Comment: +1 for being closer to correct than anyone else. You should quite your expansion of `$i`, however.

Answer (score 2):

Before you choose your answer you might want to make sure it deals correctly with file names like:

```
My brother's 12" records.tar.gz
```

If you have GNU Parallel installed:

```
ls result*.tar.gz | parallel tar zxvf
```

If you prefer without the pipe:

```
parallel tar zxvf ::: result*.tar.gz
```

I often want to make sure the unpacked files are in a dir of its own, so:

```
ls result*.tar.gz | parallel mkdir {.}\;cd {.}\;tar zxvf ../{}
```

or:

```
parallel "mkdir {.};cd {.};tar zxvf ../{}" ::: result*.tar.gz
```

Watch the intro video to learn more: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OpaiGYxkSuQ

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried piping?

Something like this ought to work:

`ls *.tar.gz | while read line; do tar -xzvf "${line}"; done`

EDIT:

Also, tar will overwrite files when it extracts. To avoid this, try one of these (from the man page):

```
-k, --keep-old-files
      keep existing files; don't overwrite them from archive

--keep-newer-files
      do not overwrite files which are newer than the archive
```

EDIT:
Avoid white space error "$line"

Comment: tested this on my local, but doesn't seem to work. edit: on mac os x, btw.

Comment: Sorry about that. I just tested this, and this should work. I missed the variable. This should list all of the files, then read them in one by one and apply the untar.

Comment: Also, watch out. Tar will overwrite duplicates. Make sure you know what's in it before you untar.

Comment: follow up, how can I not overwrite duplicates and rename to others? Basically what is inside result.tar.gz packages are the same output files...

Comment: http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?tar  Try searching for it: / is search, just like in Vim.

Comment: @tjameson: help you to edit your answer $line should be quoted to avoid white spaces error

Comment: I added curly brackets for good measure too. Can't be too safe these days.

Comment: @tjameson: the --keep-newer-file would override the old file. How can the linux system rename the file automaically?

Comment: You're getting into logic question here. The best idea would be to extract each tar into it's own directory then merge them. Nautilus (GUI on Gnome) will manage conflicts like this, but this would be a manual copy. I don't think tar supports this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like this

echo *.tar.gz | xargs -n 1 tar -zxvf